# why does the author use the 아/어라 structure in the commands highlighted below?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I'm studying an advanced Korean book. The book contains the following passage:

> 돈을 모으는 가장 쉬운 재테크는 자신이 가지고 있는 통장 관리를 어떻게 하느냐에 있다. 통장 관 리가 재테크의 기본이 되는 것이다. 자신의 통장을 용도별, 유형별로 잘 나누거나 합칠 필요가 있다. 통장 관리만 잘해도 돈이 다른 곳으로 샐 리가 없다.
>
> **우선, 급여 통장은 합쳐라**. 급여 통장은 매달 급여를 받고 고정적으로 지출을 관리하는 통장이다. 소득이 들어오고 나가는 용도로 가능하면 한 개로 합쳐서 사용하는 게 좋다. 돈이 어떻게 들어오고 나 가는지 한눈에 파악할 수 있어서 가계부 쓰는 효과를 누릴 수 있다. 공과금, 전화료 등 기본 지출의 자 동이체가 완료된 후 다음날 일정 금액이 우선 투자 통장으로 이체되도록 설정한다.
>
> **둘째, 투자 통장은 늘려라**. 결혼 자금, 자녀 교육 자금, 주택 자금, 노후 자금 등 생애 주기별로 구체 적으로 나누어 투자 목적에 맞는 금융 상품에 자동이체를 연결해야 한다. 이때 금융 상품의 이체일은 가급적 같은 날로 정하는 것이 관리하는 데 편리하다. 통장 정리 시 매월 같은 거래 내역이 반복해서 표기되기 때문에 자신이 어떤 금융 상품에 얼마나 투자하고 있는지 쉽게 확인이 가능하다. 자녀용, 노 후용 등으로 목적을 미리 정해놓고 돈을 넣기 시작하면 막연하게 돈을 모을 때보다 동기부여가 되어 효과적이다 [.....]

I understand the entire content of this passage. However, as far as I know, in argumentative essays (like in newspapers or in Topik writing exams), when used with imperative sentences we have to use (으)라 structure, not 아/어라 structure (아/어라 structure is only used in 반말). So why does the author use the 아/어라 structure in the commands highlighted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-아/어, -아/어라, and -(으)라 are all viable imperative endings in different usage contexts (in addition, -아/어 is also used declaratively and -아/어라 as an exclamation).

1. -아/어 = in everyday situation (sounds personal).  이거 먹어, 빨리 와, 두려워 말아/마.
   (-(으)세요 is the polite version).
2. -아/어라 = commanding from a higher position (can sometimes be used literarily).  이거 먹어라, 빨리 와라, 두려워 말아라/마라.
3. -(으)라 = only used in literary contexts. 과거의 실패는 잊으라, 같은 실수를 반복하지 말라, 두려워 말라.

Applying them to your example:

> 1. 급여 통장은 합쳐. Inappropriate in an essay-style writing.
> 2. 급여 통장은 합쳐라. Direct and compelling writing - not the most polite but strong.
> 3. 급여 통장은 합치라. Most appropriate in this kind of writing but weaker than 합쳐라.

So it all depends on the context. if a girl is giving some cookies to her sister, she'd say the more personal form 이거 먹어, while a mother is more likely to say to her daughter 이거 먹어라.  먹으라 would never be used in a daily situation but only in writings intended for people at large.  When spoken, -아/어라 is only used for someone younger.   It sits in between the two extreme cases.
(But in a quoted clause, -(으)라 is the standard form, as in 엄마가 저녁을 먹으라고 하셨다 - 먹어라고 is not used in indirect quoting)

There are more specialized imperative forms too, such as -(으)십시오 (similar but more polite than -아/어라), -거라 (colloquial, from even higher position than -아/어라), -ㄹ지어라 (even more literary than -(으)라 and sounds almost like a wish ).

Comment: You have helped me understand a lot more about Korean, not only in this issue but also in other matters. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're more than welcome and thanks for the nice word 